# Help me understand the simple vector concept!!!(studying all alone)

Tags: vectors

[image]

As vector **V**, which has only x and y components, rotates from point A to B, x increases and y increases.
I got this point. It's simple Cartesian coordinate analysis.
But why do vector components $v_{x}$ and $v_{y}$ behave different?
$v_{x}$ increases but $v_{y}$ decreases. Why?
Even if they are vector components, in the end, aren't they on the same Cartesian coordinates?

I think that $v_{x}=x$ and $v_{y}=y$
Am I wrong?
I think this is the point that is getting me keep confusing.

Could you explain why exactly $v_{x}$ and $v_{y}$ represent?

Comment: That's not just a move; it's a rotation.

Comment: I edited. does it have to do with rotation?

Comment: I understand your confusion. The vector $v$ at point $A$ has $(v_x, v_y)=(0, |v|)$, where $|v|$ is the length of $v$, not $(-1, 0)$.

Comment: what about at point B? still confusing...

Comment: The vector has two components: $v_x$ and $v_y$. The first, $v_x$ measures how much the vector points to the right and the second, $v_y$ measures how much the vector points up. At $A$ the vector points straight up so it doesn't point to right at all, ($v_x=0$), and $v_y$ has its maximum value. At point $B$, the vector points a little to the right and less upward.

Answer (score 1):

A vector doesn't include information about the location of the arrow it represents; it only reprents the *difference* between the positions of the arrow's endpoints. So vectors don't "move" from one location to another, they just change direction and size.

We can draw the same vector in different places. For example, the vector $v=(0,-2)$ (with $v_x=0, v_y=-2$) might be drawn as an arrow from the point $(10,10)$ to the point $(10,8)$, or as an arrow from the point $(5,5)$ to the point $(5,3)$. It's the same vector either way.

Answer (score 0):

caus $|Vx|^2 + |Vy|^2 = |V|^2$;

as |V| is unchanged;

so if Vx increased ,Vy will decreased;

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: how I understood is that v at point A is (0, |v|) and at point B, it is (x>0, y<|v|). so $v_{x})$ increases while $v_{y}$ decreases